# What evidence is there that the Herodians were distinct from mainstream Phariseeism?

Tags: history, israel, pharisees

During the New Testament era were the political and religious interests of the Pharisees closely aligned with the Herodians? Or did the nationalistic elements of Phariseeism make them allies?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the last paragraph in entry the [Pharisees](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11789b.htm) on New Advent has:

> **[T]he extreme faction of the Sadducees, known as the
>   Herodians**, was in sympathy with the foreign rulers and pagan culture,
>   and even looked forward to a restoration of the national kingdom under
>   one of the descendants of King Herod. Yet we find the Pharisees making
>   common cause with the Herodians in their opposition to the Saviour
>   (Mark 3:6; 12:13, etc.).

[Herodians | Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7605-herodians) are also identified with the Sadducees.

Comment: I suggest adding that in general the Pharisees were at the opposite end of the political spectrum to the Sadduccees. The Pharisees wanted to separate from the Gentiles; the Sadduccees (and even more so the Herodians) wanted to cooperate with them. Hence, it was highly unusual for the Pharisees to be making common cause with their enemies, the Herodians.